# Getting child class info from extends construction

Tags: php, oop

I'm not quite sure how to formulate my question, so sorry in advance for this uninformative title.
So here is the problem. I have a couple of files in the same directory, each of them is a class holder. When i inherit one of the classes i need to know in which file (or more like the folder) i do it.
I don't really like the solution i came to, but still to demonstrate what exactly i mean.

foo.php

```
class Foo {
}
```

bar.php

```
include_once 'bootstrap.php' ;

class Bar extends Foo {
}

$bar = new Bar() ;
```

bootstrap.php

```
function __autoload( $class ) {
    $trace = debug_backtrace() ;
    // Here i've got the directory i need:
    $folder = dirname( $trace[ 0 ][ 'file' ] ) ; 
}
```

Is there any other (proper) way to get folder name, cause it debug_backtrace is not actually meant for this kind of operations. And not good from the performance point of view either.

Limitation: should work for php 5.2.12

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable use of debug_backtrace().
The PHP manual page is full of examples of people using it for similar purposes.

Comment: Explain what you will be using the found directory name for. The purpose of it all.

Answer (score 0):

`$folder = dirname(__FILE__)` doesn't do the job?

Comment: No, bootstrap can be situated anywhere else. I need to know exactly the directory where parent class is being invoked

Answer (score 0):

The magic constant `__FILE__` reports the file name (with path) of the file it is called in (see the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)):

> `__FILE__` : The full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned. Since PHP 4.0.2, `__FILE__` always contains an absolute path with symlinks resolved whereas in older versions it contained relative path under some circumstances.

That means you can create a method that returns the classes file name.

For example, in 'test-folder/Foo.php':

```
class Foo {

   function getFile() {
      return __FILE__;
   }

}
```

And in 'Bar.php`:

```
include 'test-folder/Foo.php';

class Bar extends Foo {

   function getParentFile() {
      return parent::getFile();
   }

}

$bar = new Bar();

echo dirname($bar ->getParentFile());
// result: C:\wamp\www\test-folder
```

EDIT: Ok, so if you want to find out where the parent class is *before* creating it, this should work (using [Reflection](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)):

```
$reflectedBar = new ReflectionClass('Bar');
$reflectedBarParent = $reflectedBar->getParentClass();
$filename = $reflectedBarParent->getFileName();
```

Comment: No, __FILE__ contains the current file path. And it can't be used before inheritance. So i can't use it in Bar class.

Comment: No, if you create a method in the parent class and call that method from the child class with "parent::getFile()" (or whatever) it will report the parent files location.

Comment: My mistake in the title. The example is more correct. I don't need the parent class, it's the child class i need.

Comment: then put the method in the child class? You've confused me about what the problem is.

Comment: It's not possible. Before i create the child object it needs to know which class it inherits, right? End there the problem goes. In addition i need the child to be more flexible that's why i'm using autoload

Comment: wierd, but ok - see new solution

Comment: Hehe, thanks a lot, but no, it's not it again. First i don't know the child class (it can be any other), and second it still gives me the parent class file name, not the child :) It seems like this problem can't be solved, i've asked several people, all say i should use this hack with debug_backtrace, not very healthy, but still fine. Thanx in any way for your time.